# Why is electricity 'the screwing force'?

Tags: electromagnetism

In one of his lectures Richard Feynman, a great genius and a '*naughty Bronx kid*', refers to to the Coulomb force, electricity as "the screwing force".

Apart from the obvious joke and *double entendre*, can you explain that original definition and in what way it is different from other forces or from an EM wave?

Answer (score 3):

I assume it refers to [Fleming's Left Hand Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fleming%27s_left-hand_rule_for_motors) for motors

Answer (score 1):

Knowing it comes from Feynman, I would think he meant that all contact forces here on earth are electrical (between the electron shells of the atoms). That includes the drive of a screwdriver, and the friction (and pleasure) generated when having sex.